# Is the following sentence correct?

Tags: translation, grammar

I want to translate to Chinese this phrase: "Please, write on the parcel  "some-text" ".

Is this variant correct? 请在包裹外面上写下 "some-text".

Thank you.

Comment: why not?, the only question may be is "外面" needed, or is "在包裹上" sufficient, see examples in jukuu for 在包裹上 to see that this is sufficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my opinion, it is better to use 请在包裹上写下 "some-text".

Answer (score 0):

We don't usually say“外面上”，instead，we will say “包裹外面” or just “包裹上”, and they have the same meaning here.

Answer (score 0):

This expression can be understood by Chinese. But usually native Madrin speaker will express it like this "请在包裹上写下" or "请在包裹外面写下".